# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator that only stretches and does not compress

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a 1D Potential $V(x) = (m \omega^2 x^2)/2$ of a harmonic oscillator.
Suppoese that the spring can only be stretched, so that the potential becomes
$V = \infty$ for $x<0$. What are the energy levels of this system?

I am having trouble starting this problem. 
I know that the energies of a normal harmonic oscillator are given by
$E_n = \hbar \omega(n+ 1/2)$. So my guess is that the energy can be represented by this for x >= 0 but what about at $x < 0$? Would I set up boundary conditions for the potentials at x = 0 or boundary conditions for the wave functions at $x = 0$?

Comment: Hint: take a look at the first few wavefunctions for the QHO [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb340.gif).  Some of these cannot be solutions to this modified QHO problem but not all.

Comment: I know that for n=0, the solutions do not match and cannot match therefore the ground state cannot be a solution. But as for the rest of them, from my perspective, it seems as though they can all be solutions. But this wouldn't make sense since the QHO here is essentially half of a QHO, therefore only half of the solutions would exist, but which ones?

Comment: The infinite barrier at the origin means the solution must have a node there.

Comment: Ah, i see, therefore the only solutions to this QHO would be those that have a node at x = 0, namely the odd solutions. n = 1,3,5,7..